# question on geometry circle

Tags: geometry

The ﬁgure below shows a broken piece of a circular plate made of glass.C is the midpoint of AB, and D is the midpoint of arc AB. Given that AB = 24 cm and CD = 6 cm, how do I get what is the radius of the plate in centimetres? (The ﬁgure is not drawn to scale and given figure is not semi circular arc)
[image: .)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lengths of all line segments are as shown

[image]

By power of a point, $AC \cdot CB = DC \cdot CE$. That is, $12 \cdot 12 = 6 \cdot (2R – 6)$.

Then, $R = 15$.

Comment: Is it  necessary to show points $D,C,O,E$ are collinear.Then apply power of point.

Comment: @Ayushakj Yes. Both ACB and DCOE must be straight chords. Since C and D are the midpoints of AB and arc AB respectively, the point O, C, and D will automatically be collinear on the radius OCD. Also, OE is just another radius created by extending DCO. Hence, D, C, O, E are collinear.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

for an analytical solution:

In a coordinate system with origin $C$, and $AB$ on the $x-$axis, the coordinates of the three points on the circle are: $A=(-12,0)$, $B=(12,0)$ and $D=(0,6)$. Put these coordinates in the generic equation of a circle: $x^2+y^2+ax+by+c=0$ and you have a system of three linear equations in $a,b,c$:

Solving the system you can find the center and radius of the circle.

For a geometric solution:

Let $O$ the center of the circle. For the rectangle triangle $AOC$ we have: $\overline{AO}^2=\overline{AC}^2+\overline{CO}^2$ with $\overline{AO}=r$ and $\overline{CO}=r-\overline{DC}$.

Answer (score 1):

[Diagram of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAk9D.png)

Construction:OB,OA

Proof:
Since arc AD and arc DB are equal, the angle subtended by the arcs at the center will be equal.

So, angle AOC=angle BOC

Let the angle AOC(=angle BOC) be  θ

Since AB is a chord and it is being bisected by the radius, the angle that the 
radius OD makes with AB is 90°

Considering triangle OBC,

With respect to  θ,

perpendicular=>OB=12 cm

base=>OC=(**R-6**) cm    [Since R is the radius and CD is 6 cm]

hypotenuse=>OB=R cm

Using Pythagoras' Theorem,

(12)^2+(R-6)^2=R^2

Solving this we get R=15 cm.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Let OC=x (where O is the center of circle).
Now,
Radius=x+6=OA
In triangle AOC, (x+6)^2 = x^2 + 12^2....               [Pythagoras Theorem]
On solving, we get x=9 i.e. R = x + 6 = 9 + 6 = 15cm

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).